# How to flat array in zustand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, zustand

I have a brands list array, every brand object has a brand name & products

So the first time, I pushed the new brand object to the brands list, and that's work well,

Now if I want to push a new brand to the brands list and keep the previous brand data it does not work as expected.

and it looks like this

[image: issue]

the expected should be like this

[image: expected]

I'm trying to use flat() but not work here

minimal reproduction [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-flower-tvju7s?file=/src/App.js)

**Code**

```
import create from 'zustand';
import {persist} from 'zustand/middleware';
import {zustandStorage} from '../utils/Storage';

export const useFavoritesStore = create(
  persist(
    set => ({
      brandsFavoritesList: [],
      updateFavList: brandData => {
        set(state => ({
          brandsFavoritesList:
            // check if there are any brands on the list before
            state.brandsFavoritesList.length > 0
              ? state.brandsFavoritesList.map(brand =>
                  // if the brand exists before pushing new products
                  brand.tenant === brandData?.tenant
                    ? {
                        ...brand,
                        products: [...brand.products, ...brandData.products],
                      }
                    : // if the brand does not exist before push the new brand data to the brandsFavoritesList 
    // Issue here...
                      [...state.brandsFavoritesList, brandData].flat(),
                )
              : [...state.brandsFavoritesList, {...brandData}],
        }));
      },
    }),
    {
      name: 'favorites-local',
      getStorage: () => zustandStorage,
    },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want something like

```
function updateBrandsFavoritesList(brandsFavoritesList, brandData) {
  const brandIndex = brandsFavoritesList.findIndex((brand) => brand.tenant === brandData.tenant);
  if (brandIndex < 0) {
    // This is a new brand, append it to the list.
    return [...brandsFavoritesList, brandData];
  }
  // This is an existing brand, update it.
  const existingBrand = brandsFavoritesList[brandIndex];
  const updatedBrand = {
    ...existingBrand,
    products: [...existingBrand.products, ...brandData.products],
  };
  return brandsFavoritesList.map((brand, index) => (index === brandIndex ? updatedBrand : brand));
}

const updateFavList = (brandData) => {
  if (!brandData) return;
  set(({brandsFavoritesList}) => ({
    brandsFavoritesList: updateBrandsFavoritesList(brandsFavoritesList, brandData),
  }));
}
```

– no need for `flat`.

The complex logic of finding and updating a brand has been moved to a separate free function which should be easier to e.g. test in isolation too.

(Even better still would be to use TypeScript so errors would be more obvious...)

Comment: Hey @AKX first of all thank u, but not work. 
as I see here 
`brandsFavoritesList.map(existingBrand =>...)`
 I need to push the new brand to fav List if it does not exist before but in ur answer u push the `existingBrand` so it will not push any new brand

Comment: Right, just a sec...

Comment: @OliverD See revised answer :)

Comment: Thank you @AKX, but there is a small issue I fixed in the first condition, 
`brandData` it's an `object` so we can't spread it.
so it should be like this  `return [...brandsFavoritesList, brandData];`, Can u please update it so I can accept your answer with the fixed?

Comment: @OliverD Sure, fixed.